# How can I have one button execute two actions?

Tags: php

Is it possible to have the one “Save” button execute these two actions?

Action 1:

```
<td>
<?php
    $target = TRoute::_("index.php?option=com_adsmanager&task=save"); 
    if ($this->nbcats == 1)
    {
        $this->displaySingleCatChooser(@$this->content->id,$this->conf,"com_adsmanager",$this->cats,$this->catid);
    }
?>
</table>
```

Action 2:

```
<input type="button" onclick="countDown(this.form)" value="SAVE"><p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain what each does. It's possible you can call your JavaScript function, then call the PHP via AJAX.

Comment: Action 1 saves information entered into a form and opens a new page. Action 2 starts a counter. I would like to see the counter appear on the new page also.

Comment: You can do this using AJAX

Comment: Thanks Nicarus; it looks like I now need to try and learn AJAX also! A lot of learning for one or two commands. I better make a start.

Comment: Hi again Nicarus. Is AJAX suitable? The first line in the W3schools states that "AJAX is about updating parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page". But I need both actions to go to another page; the same page as Action 1 originally went to. Do I still need AJAX for this application?

Comment: I don't know what your `countDown()` function actually does, but if it requires calling a PHP script/page, then you will most likely need AJAX. If that function is ONLY Javascript, then you may not need to.

Comment: Thanks Nicarus, I somehow got the new page to open but with the wrong button and missing a lot of info. I'm going to see if someone with more skills than me can work on it, if I can't find someone I'll be back with more questions. Thanks for your time.